# Can I include a Wix fragment by referencing a property defined in it?

Tags: wix

I'm using Wix 3.8. I have a Wix library, and in its wxs file I have a Fragment which has a property:

```
<Fragment>
  <!-- The following property is only used for reference -->
  <Property Id="ReferenceProp"></Property>

  <!-- other stuff here ... -->
</Fragment>
```

In my setup project I want to use the contents of this fragment, but I want to do it in an easy way, so I tried adding a `PropertyRef` to to the `ReferenceProp` property defined above. I got an error:

```
Unresolved reference to symbol 'Property:ReferenceProp'
```

However, if I change said property to be a `ComponentGroup` (and the ref to a `ComponentGroupRef`) then it works. Is this a bug? Is it designed to work in that unintuitive way? Or did I miss something?

**Edit:** to be clear I did have my `PropertyRef` inside my `Product` element when I got the above error.

**Edit2:** I knew I had seen some info before explicitly stating I could use PropertyRef to pull in a fragment. Here is the quote from the book Wix 3.6 A developer's Guide to Windows Installer XML by Nick Ramirez:

> For example, properties, which are variables that you can use to store data, are represented by Property elements and could be stored in a separate file within a Fragment element. Then, by referencing just one of them in your main source file with a PropertyRef element, you'd pull all of them into your project."

Either that book is wrong, or this was a feature that they removed, or a newly introduced bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to link to one component to load a whole fragment.

To quote John Cooper:

> You need a reference element to any one bit inside the fragment.  The
>   way Wix linking currently works, a linkage to one item in a fragment
>   brings in the whole fragment.
>
> For example, if you have a Component element in a fragment, you would
>   link in the fragment using a ComponentRef with the appropriate Id
>   attribute.

And Ian Williams

> Yep, you need to reference
>   something in a fragment (DirectoryRef, ComponentRef, etc) to load the
>   fragment (it will all be loaded, note).
>
> Also remember to include allt he .wxs files in your call to candle and
>   light

http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/How-to-reference-a-wxs-file-from-another-td7334084.html

**Edit**

It is possible with PropertyRef too. I just checked it myself. Change this:

```
<Property Id="ReferenceProp"></Property>
```

To this:

```
<Property Id="ReferenceProp" Value="1" />
```

You need to set a value.

Comment: I have a book: Wix 3.6 A Developer's Guide to Windows Installer, and from it this quote: "... properties, ... could be stored in a separate file within a Fragment element. Then, by referencing just one of them in your main source file with a PropertyRef element, you'd pull all of them into your project." Is the book wrong? Or was this a feature that was taken out? Or is it a newly introduced bug?

Comment: I have the book too and I re-checked. You are correct. So I tested this again and it does work. I'll edit my answer and code, check again in a minute.

Comment: This is the right answer, in order for a property reference to load the fragment, the property needs a value (your edit).

Answer (score 2):

If you create a Property inside a Fragment, you will need to add the PropertyRef to the Product, this way:

File with fragment:

```
<Fragment>
  <Property Id="SQL_CE_64">
    <RegistrySearch Id="SqlCe64Search"
                    Root="HKLM"
                    Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\DA93DA4DE19033D4BBB2956FCF8BDA3C"
                    Name="Version"
                    Type="raw" />
  </Property>
</Fragment>
```

File with the Product tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product ...>
    <PropertyRef Id="SQL_CE_64" />
    ...
  </Product>
</Wix>
```

Comment: I already do put it in the `Product`. I'll update my question to explicitly state that.